# re-arrange items into an array with no similar items next to each other

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have a collection of blocks. 12 are red, 8 are blue, 5 are yellow and 1 is green. I need to create an algorithm that outputs these objects into a single array with no red blocks next to each other, no blue blocks next to each other, etc. The output should look something like this:

red, blue, red, blue, red, blue, yellow, blue, green, red, yellow, etc.

In my programming experiences so far, I'me come to places where I had to write an algorithm to do this more than once. The last time I did it was about 2 years ago working for a startup. I implemented such an algorithm in python, but the source code is not available. I do remember it took me at least 100 lines to create.

Does this algorithm have a name? I don't want to have to implement it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know of a name for this problem. Below is the algorithm I came up with to solve it.

You need to keep track of # of each block remaining.

```
repeat:
output 1 block of largest color set.
output 1 block from the second largest color set.
```

the output:

> r b r b r b r b r g r b r g r b r g r b r g r b g y

note: before running this algorithm, you need to check to see if the largest color set's size is greater than 1 + the sum of the other color's sizes. If it is, there is no solution.

note: picking the from the second largest set is not required. The second pick in the loop can come from any of the non-largest color sets.

Comment: Thats more or less what I came up with, except you don't need to pull from the second highest set, only from any 'non-highest' set.

Comment: @priestc I believe treating the second most frequent set specially is necessary somehow. For example `r r r r g b w c c c`, if we use up `g b w` when padding for `r r r r`, then we are left with all `c c c`, which is not desired.

Comment: @Icn, after we output 2 r, c is now largest set and would be output before any more r.  ex: `r g r b c ....`

Answer (score 1):

Just off of the top of my head - create a queue that contains all the blocks you want to insert in decreasing quantity (i.e. using the example above the queue would contain 12 reds then 8 blues then 5 yellows then 1 green). Insert an element from the queue into every even index of the array and then every odd index (i.e. insert a red block at index 
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22, then insert blues at 24,1,3,5,7,9,11,13 then insert yellows at 15,17,19,21 and insert the green at 23)

Note that for some combinations of blocks this task is impossible - before running the algorithm you have to check that the set of blocks with the highest number has no more blocks than the sum of all the blocks divided by 2

Comment: your example is wrong. you list there being 13 red blocks. Your algorithm also has a problem if there are 12/8/8/8 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to check if such array exists.

   e.g. if you have 4 reds and only 1 blue, then it doesn't exist

   So if the number of largest collection is smaller than the sum of all other collections minus 1, then there is no valid solution
2. Then you just put all items of your largest collection, say red, there as a list.

   Between each item of the list, it is a spot you can insert other elements

   ```
   e.g. _ red _ red _ red _ red _ red _ red ...
   ```
3. Now you can insert other items collection by collection to those spots. The order of the collections doesn't matter.

   ```
   e.g. blue red blue red blue red blue red yellow red yellow red _ red _ red ..
   ```

   You need to consume those spots always from left to right (or always from right to left).

   Whenever you run out of spots, you start again from left (or right) to insert items to the new spots.

   ```
   e.g. green blue _ red _ blue _ red _ blue _ red _ blue _ red _ yellow _ red ...
   ```

Comment: You answer would say that the collection 3-red 2-blue ( 3 !< 2-1) would have no solution. clearly this is wrong: as the array { red,blue,red,blue,red} is a valid solution.

Comment: @ColinD No I mean if it's smaller then there is no valid solution.. maybe I wasn't clear, just updated the post